# Paginating iterator in Python

Tags: python, iterator

I am trying to create a function that takes in a python iterator and returns an iterator of iterators, with each item being a fixed size set of items from the original iterator. In other words:

```
paginate([a, b, c, d], 2) -> [[a,b],[c,d]]
```

My code, so far works, but returns a zero length page if the length of the iterator is divisible by the page size.

```
def paginate(iterator, pageSize):
    hasMore = True

    def pageIter():
        print (1)
        try:
            for _ in range(pageSize):
                yield next(iterator)
        except StopIteration as e:
            nonlocal hasMore
            hasMore = False
            raise e

    def pager():
            while hasMore:
                yield pageIter()
                if not hasMore:
                    raise StopIteration()

    return pager()
```

I am aware that itertools has a recipe but that code seems to fill incomplete pages with `None`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work with all iterables, not just lists:

```
class Paginator:
    def __init__(self, iterable, page_len=3):
        self.iterable = iterable
        self.page_len = page_len

    def __iter__(self):
        page = []
        for i in self.iterable:
            page.append(i)
            if len(page) == self.page_len:
                yield page 
                page = []
        if page:
            yield page

p = Paginator([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3)  
for i in p:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `take` recipe from `itertools`:

```
def take(n, iterable):
    "Return first n items of the iterable as a list"
    return list(islice(iterable, n))
```

And then:

```
def unchain(iterable, n):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        result = take(n, iterable)
        if result:
            yield result
        else:
            raise StopIteration

>>> list(unchain(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2))
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
>>> list(unchain(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 2))
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Short oneliner () iterator function without imports:

```
def splitby(it, n):
    for a in range(0, len(it), n):
        yield it[a:a+n]
```

Result

```
>>> list(splitby([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],2))
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version:

```
def chunk(it, size):
    """Chunk an iterator into tuples of the given size"""
    it = iter(it)
    return iter(lambda: tuple(itertools.islice(it, size)), ())
```

I honestly can't remember where I got this from. It's not my invention.

If you want an of lists rather than of tuples (presumably so that you can modify the contents in-place) then replace `tuple` with `list`.